TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object nodemon
when I use nodemon in the VSCode terminal I get this error
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\wBk\StudioProjects\devmob\lib\flutter\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wBk\StudioProjects\devmob\lib\flutter\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:227:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\wBk\StudioProjects\devmob\lib\flutter\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:224:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wBk\StudioProjects\devmob\lib\flutter\backend\index.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)

Node.js v20.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
this is my index.js code:
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080 || process.env.PORT
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb")

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('port running on '+port)
})

and this is my router.js code:
const express = require('express')
const User = require('../models/user.model')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/signin',(req,res)=>{
   console.log('hello world')
})

module.exports = router


Please, provide a way to reproduce. There's a problem that you don't use a router that the answer explains, but there's no problem with incorrect app.use that could cause the error too. "when I use nodemon in the VSCode terminal" - does this mean the error doesn't occur when you run nodemon outside VSC and run the app without nodemon?


First import the router in your  index.js .
 const userRouter = require('./routes/router');



2.then use the router with a base path in your index.js
 app.use('/user', userRouter);

this will resolve your requires a middleware function but got a Object  error .
the error message Router.use() requires a middleware function but got an Object indicates that you are trying to use a router object incorrectly and By correctly importing the router and using it with app.use('/user', userRouter);, you ensure that Express correctly interprets the router as a set of middleware functions for handling requests to /user and its subpaths.

please explain the root of the problem and how your solution would solve the issue.

@Raeisi updated the answer
